# How can I ensure that pytest fixture function is executed only once irrespective of howmany calls within same module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

First I had a class in original code

```
#mycode.py

class MyClass:
   def __init__(self,value):
       self.value = value
   
   def run(self):
       return self.value

   def set(self,value):
       self.value=value
```

I am trying to test cases for this code, I am taking input using 'pytest_generate_tests'

```
#test_mycode.py

def pytest_generate_tests():
    # manipulation to point variable 'data_file'to input.json 
    parameter_name ="input"
    if parameter_name in metafunc.funcargnames:
        with open(tests_file) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
            metafunc.parametrize(parameter_name, data["test_cases"], scope="module")
```

And my fixture within same file follows like:

```
#test_mycode.py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def dummy_object(input): #from input file, instantiating
    return MyClass(input["data"])

def test_set(dummy_object,input):
    dummy_object.set(input["value"])   # input.json is '{ "test_cases":[{"data":5},{"value":6}]}'
    assert dummy_object.value==input["value"]

def test_run(dummy_object):
    assert dummy_object.run()==6
```

But it's returning 5 instead of 6 , means creating another instance of MyClass.
Someone please tell me how can I make sure such that one object is instantiated.
Since scope I mentioned is "module", I thought only one will get created but that's not the case

Comment: I just tested your code - works fine for me. Are you sure you are using the same code, and the same test file?

Comment: Sorry for my inconvenience, Actually I am writing test cases for the company in which I joined recently. I did not want to show exact code , so tried to replicate. just updated the code where fixture function also takes 'input' argument in my case. In this case, It is failing as dummy_object gets called 2 times

Comment: This won't work - `input` is not a fixture, so you cannot use it as the argument in another fixture (`dummy_object` in this case). If you meant to add it to `test_run` instead - this would also pass, so I'm not sure what you are doing here.

Comment: Added 'params' property in @pytest.fixture(params= call_back()), In call_back function, I returned data loaded from input.json. Then, I can ensure that only one instance is created irrespective of as many appearances of fixture. Anyways, Thanks for your valuable time for sorting out my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to acheive it,we can use 'params' property in @pytest.fixture and call function to load input from input.json

```
def initiate_object():
#use os module to point 'dir_name' to 'input.json'
with open(dir_name) as test_data
    my_data = json.load(test_data)
    return my_data['test_cases'] #usually list for multiple inputs

@pytest.fixture(scope="module",params=initiate_object())
def dummy_object(request):  #it must take request param
return MyClass(request.param['data'])
```

It ensures single instantiation